# Any clue what this error message could mean (related to dispatcher)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reason, I cannot seem to find the exact source of the following error: `"TypeError: this.$Dispatcher_callbacks is undefined"`

I know that the error hos something to do with the Event Emitter in my store, But i do not even have the slightest clue how to fix it

```jsx
var appStore = Assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    emitChange: function(){
        this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
    },
    addChangeListener: function(callback){
        this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    },
    removeChangeListener: function(callback){
        this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT,callback);
    },
    getCart: function(){
        return cart; 
    },
    getCatalog: function(){
        return catalog;
    },
    // I suspect that the error lies somewhere below
    dispatcherIndex: AppDispatcher.register(function(payload){

        var action = payload.action; 

        switch(action.actionType){
          case Constants.ADD_ITEM:
            API.addItem(payload.action.item);
            break;

          case Constants.REMOVE_ITEM:
            API.removeItem(payload.action.index);
            break;

          case Constants.INCREASE_ITEM:
            API.increaseItem(payload.action.index);
            break;

          case Constants.DECREASE_ITEM:
            API.decreaseItem(payload.action.index);
            break;
        }

        AppDispatcher.emitChange();

        return true;
    })
});
```

Any clue will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Probably something to do with the Assign. Not sure why though. In a project I worked on we used lodash.extend. That worked great. ```_.extend( { },  EventEmitter.prototype, { .....```

Comment: Or can it be that you are doing ```AppDispatcher.emitChange();```, are you trying to do ```appStore.emitChange()```?

Comment: Find that error message and set a breakpoint to see what it's looking for.

Comment: found the error. Thank you